# How to remove root node from heap?

Tags: tree, binary, heap

I have a heap: 90 80 80 40 10 20 50. I have to remove the root node 3 times. What leaf will it take its place?

I have tried removing the 90 root node and replacing it with 50, as it is in the last position of the heap. But I also saw it is possible to replace it with 40, as it is the last left child. What solution is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing it with 50 is correct, because it maintains the property of heap structures which is being **complete** from top to bottom and left to right.

A **complete** binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible.
Hence removing the rightmost bit keeps the tree as far left as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for removing the root node from a binary heap are:

1. Replace the root node with the lowest, right-most item on the heap.
2. Decrement the count.
3. Sift the new value down the heap to its new position.

For example, given your array, `[90, 80, 80, 40, 10, 20, 50]` you have the heap:

```
            90
        80      80
      40  10  20  50
```

You remove 90, and replace with 50, giving you:

```
            50
        80      80
      40  10  20
```

Now, you sift down. The rules for sifting down is that you swap with the largest of the two children. In this case the two children are equal, so you could swap with either one. The result is a valid heap either way. 80 is at the top, and the two nodes at the next level are either [80, 50], or they're [50, 80].

The reason you take the lowest, right-most item is to maintain the heap property. Remember: the heap is a complete binary tree, with all the levels completely full except for possibly the last, which is left-filled. Let me show you a slightly different heap where that could cause a problem:

```
         90
     66      74
   65  11  70  50
```

Now, if you were to replace 90 with 65, the first problem you have is a hole in your array. That is, you'd have `[65, 66, 74, __, 11, 70, 50]`. That'd be easy enough to fix by shifting everything beyond the empty space over to the left one, giving you `[65, 66, 74, 11, 70, 50]`. But now let's view that as a heap:

```
         65
     66      74
   11  70  50
```

The rules for sifting down say that you have to swap with the largest child. In this case that's 74. But if you do that you end up with this invalid heap:

```
         74
     66      65
   11  70  50
```

And you can't just decide to swap with the smaller child because if you did then 66 would be the root. Either way you end up with an invalid heap.

There are two reasons you replace the root with the lowest, right-most node (the last item in the array):

1. Correctness. By removing the last item, you're guaranteed not to affect the relationships of any other nodes. Removing from anywhere else can invalidate the heap.
2. Efficiency. It's trivial to remove the last item from an array. Removing from anywhere else is potentially an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a binary heap is a *complete binary tree*. This means that:

1. Each node has either two children or is a leaf.
2. All the levels of the tree, except possible the last one, are fully filled
3. If the last level is not complete, the nodes of that level are filled **from left to right**.

In your example, if you would remove the left-most leaf (40), the third condition is no longer maintained: there is now a gap at the extreme left of the last level.

The only node you can remove *without* breaking any of these three conditions is the rightmost leaf. In other words, it is the only node you can remove to arrive at the tree-shape that the final result should have.

This is why you need to replace the root node (the one you want to remove) with node 50 (which is removed instead, and its value overwrites the original root value).